# ant property conditional on another property

Tags: java, ant, properties, version

I would like to do the following in ant

```
if javac.version >= 1.7
then
  <property name="myproperty" value="somevalue"/>
else
  <property name="myproperty" value="someothervalue"/>
endif
```

Looks simple enough but not familiar enough with ant to do this

Any assistance appreciated

Comment: [This](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) and [this](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) might be of help.

Comment: [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has [if-else](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the condition task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) to check if the contents of the java version system property contains the  version you need. Here is an example:

```
<project name="test" default="target">
    <target name="target">
        <condition property="property" value="value1" else="value2">
            <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.7"/>
        </condition>
        <echo>Java version: ${java.version}. Result: ${property}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Output:

```
Java version: 1.7.0_60. Result: value1
```